# Cannot connect to postgresql database from init.d script (Debian)

Tags: debian, postgresql, sysvinit

A script that runs just fine normally fails when put into an /etc/init.d/ script (consolenew), to activate at bootup.
Specifically, it cannot open the PostgreSQL database, giving the error: `could not connect to server: Connection refused`

init.d/consolenew settings:

```
#### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: consolenew
# Required-Start: $all $postgresql $network
# Required-Stop: $all $postgresql $network 
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 
# Short-Description: ....
#### END INIT INFO

/path-to-file/consolenew.sh &
```

System is Debian 8. What is missing here to get PostgreSQL to work?

Answer (score 0):

The program works (i.e. PostgreSQL loads in time to be connected to) if I move it to the Init script of the Gnome Desktop Manager (/etc/gdm3/Init).

I will use that unless someone has another solution.

EDIT: A systemd script also works, if After: postgresql service is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the script placed in  the `/etc/init.d/scripts` activated from user which not represented in the postgresql RDBMS (and most likely this user  is `root`). Check that your script in  the `/etc/init.d/scripts` set up to be activated from the user/role which exists in postgersql, and this user allowed to connect in `pg_gba.conf` file.

Comment: In pg_hba.conf all the settings are set to trust. the shell script explicitly switches users to the correct one to connect.